# Read local json file and show the data in UI for blazor server

Tags: json, user-interface, blazor, blazor-server-side, readfile

I have one blazor. Net 5 web application.I have added one json file. Need to call that json file to razor page and show the data in UI for blazor server.

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http

@if (employees == null)
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}
else
{
    @foreach (var employee in employees) 
    { 
        <p>Employee ID: @employee.Id</p>
    }
}


@code {
    private Employee[] employees;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        employees = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Employee[]>("employee.json");
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Getting the following error for the above code snippet -

```
Invalid operation exception: cannot provide a value for property 'http' on type 

There is no registered service for type System.Net.Http.HttpClient
```

Kindly help with example. It is a huge blocker.

Comment: I don't believe that error message would be emitted by the framework (it would be extremely unprofessional to say "not working"), so presumably you are outputting that message.  You're on the hook for explaining why you are displaying that error message.

Comment: Kindly check the question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using dependency injection for an instance of HttpClient:

`@inject HttpClient Http`

and the error message is indicating that no `HttpClient` service has been registered.  You need to register an `HttpClient` service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Or you could use `IHttpClientFactory` and call CreateClient();